# rewrite rule in .htaccess - question mark

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to create rewrite rule inside my app in file .htaccess. The question is quite easy, how to create something like this:

From

```
www.mydomain.com/category-name?p=2
```

To

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?category=category-name&page=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*category-name/?p=(.*) index.php?category=category-name&page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)p=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&page=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```